# Setting width of LinearLayout dynamically?

Tags: android, width, android-linearlayout

I want to make my own custom "progress bar". I do this by drawing to linear layouts, each with a different color. After that I want to assign a width to each of them to make it look as a progress bar. The thing I am having right now:

XML file of an item of my CustomAdapter (in Gridview):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#33c2bd" >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/lineScore"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#eef05e" 
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvLevelScore"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/lineScoreTotal"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#0d7975" 
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvLevelScore"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lineScore"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in the CustomAdapter class under the getView method I am trying to set the lineScoreTotal to 80% of the width of the item:

```
double viewWidth = (double) mView.getWidth();
            int widthScoreBar = (int) (viewWidth * 0.8);
            LinearLayout ln = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.lineScoreTotal);
            ln.layout(0, 2, widthScoreBar, -1);
```

However, it is doing nothing... Am I applying the wrong code to set the width? Or is my idea of using LinearLayout to draw those "bars" maybe the wrong thing to do?

EDIT getView method:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        View mView = v;

        if (mView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mView = vi.inflate(R.layout.levelselector_item, null);

        }

        TextView level = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvLevel);
        TextView levelScore = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvLevelScore);

        if (mView != null) {

            level.setText(Integer.toString(getItem(position).getLevel()));

            loadDataBase();
            int correctAnswers = myDbHelper.getCorrectAnswers(getItem(position).getLevel());
            correctAnswersPrev = 0;
            correctAnswersPrev = myDbHelper.getCorrectAnswersPrev(getItem(position).getLevel());

            String correct = Integer.toString(correctAnswers);

            levelScore.setText(correct + "/60");
            level.setTypeface(font);
            levelScore.setTypeface(font);

            LinearLayout ln = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.lineScoreTotal);
            ln.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(10, 10));
}
        return mView;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try either way

**Without Gravity**

```
ln.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

**Or with gravity**

```
ln.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting this error:
10-03 12:41:17.394: E/AndroidRuntime(27008): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams

Comment: getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()  //try this way to calculate width

Comment: Do you think that is causing the error? Suppose I just type ln.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 10)); I am still getting the error...

Comment: can you paste  getview method?

Comment: I edited my initial question and put the getview method there.

Comment: above xml is levelselector_item?

Comment: R.id.tvLevelScore & R.id.tvLevel ,textview are not in above xml.

Comment: It is just a part of the entire xml, I cropped it a bit to paste it here to the essence... they are there.

Comment: I was able to solve it: ln.getLayoutParams().height = y;
    ln.getLayoutParams().width = x;
    ln.requestLayout();

Answer (score 0):

```
ln.setLayoutParams(new
       LayoutParams(widthScoreBar,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Try setting using LayoutParams.

Comment: Thank you as well, but I am having the same error as above: 10-03 12:41:17.394: E/AndroidRuntime(27008): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams

Comment: Could you paste your stack trace ?

Comment: I hope you mean this:
10-03 12:50:24.121: E/AndroidRuntime(27724): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 12:50:24.121: E/AndroidRuntime(27724): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
10-03 12:50:24.121: E/AndroidRuntime(27724):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.findRoots(RelativeLayout.java:1303)
10-03 12:50:24.121: E/AndroidRuntime(27724):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1250)
10-03 12:50:24.121: E/AndroidRuntime(27724):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:281)